# File attributes, permissions issue

Tags: linux, shell-script, files, permissions, ownership

I have a shell script that runs on 2 machine by a job scheduler.
The script generates some text file when it is executed. 
On one system, the text file generated has the permission:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 ABCD00   abc           56 Apr 25 10:12 all_sort
```

On the other system, the same text file has the following attributes:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root     abc           56 Apr 25 10:47 all_sort
```

As told earlier, the same script is being executed by the job scheduler on two independent systems. 
I am unable to understand how the file generated on the 2nd system has the owner as `root` instead of `ABCD00`.
Can anyone help on what points I need to check?

Comment: I would assume that the "job scheduler" is running under the ownership ABCD00 on one machine and root on the other.

Comment: What user is running the jobs on the two systems? Is the file removed and then re-generated with each run? What Unix and job scheduler are the two system running?

Comment: @RamanSailopal: I have already contacted the Job scheduler team with the same query. But waiting for response. Thanks for the reply.